# Не могу разобраться почему долго крутятся часы inlinekeyboard telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Есть фрагмент кода, где пользователь нажимает inline button и должен выводится текст. Когда запускаю, чтобы проверить, долго грузится кнопка, как ускорить быстродействие?

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def openSettings(message):

    get_message_text = message.text
    print(get_message_text)

    if get_message_text == 'Настройки':
        settings_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        quality = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Качество', callback_data='quality')
        money = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Подписка', callback_data='money')
        settings_markup.add(quality, money)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Настройте бот под себя', reply_markup=settings_markup)
    elif get_message_text == 'Скачать':
        settings_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        quality = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Видео', callback_data='video')
        money = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Аудио', callback_data='audio')
        settings_markup.add(quality, money)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите формат скачивания', reply_markup=settings_markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
def video_choose(call):
    if call.data == 'video':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Все работает')
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно посылать через [answer_callback_query](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/888c7a6b0d97c376947ee7b525d4b70583acc3fc/examples/inline_keyboard_example.py#L19), чтобы телеграм получил подтверждение, что клик на inline кнопку был успешно обработан ботом

Попробуйте:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def video_choose(call):
    if call.data == 'video':
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Все работает')
```

Comment: А как сделать тогда, чтобы бот еще при этом высылал сообщение? То есть если пользователь нажимает видео, то должна высвечиватся новая инлайн клавиатура с новым текстом

Comment: @Alexseusik, попробуйте просто послать answer_callback_query без текста, а следом за ним send_message с текстом и клавиатурой